# Outlook Calendar to SharePoint 365 for everyone to view

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, outlook, office-web-apps

Perhaps this has been answered in another post and if so I apologize for taking up your time and you can just redirect me to the thread that it has been resolved under (if possible thank you).

**This is my Scenario:**

User A has an Outlook calendar that is used to create meetings, events and so forth for other users. Essentially this user manages the schedule for other users using that one calendar in their Outlook.

EG: That calendar will have meetings for User A, B, C and D

**My Question:**

I would like to sync User A's calendar in Outlook to a SharePoint Calendar  and have it display to all users in SharePoint.

Can this be done?

**What I have tried?**

1. I created a demo user account to simulate user A.
2. I created several dummy meeting requests to myself and two other people using User A's Outlook calendar.
3. I used the Sync option from the SharePoint end to connect to the Calendar in Outlook.
4. This is where my issue occurs
   a) When I go into the calendar on SharePoint to see it. All that I see is my events in the calendar and no one else's. I need the ability to see other peoples events and meetings as well.

I believe it's a permission problem somewhere as the Calendar (in SharePoint) for whatever reason only displays that logged in users events, meetings and so forth which I do not need.

My Requirement:
I need like a global view of all events displayed regardless of who is logged in on that SharePoint calendar that is connected to User A's Outlook.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To add an event to a SharePoint calendar by using Outlook. follow those steps

You can add appointments and all-day events to your SharePoint calendar, just as you add them to your Outlook calendars.

1- Open the SharePoint calendar in Outlook. On the Home tab, in the New group, 
      click the type of event that you want to add. You can also create 
     recurring events, although some custom recurrence patterns are not 
    available in SharePoint calendars.

2- Enter the information about the event, as you ordinarily do in Outlook.

3-   Click Save and Close.

4- you create a SPG e.g. (Calendar Members) there you will put your members, add this group to you calendar then alla members inside the group will have the ability to see meeting events for User A

It's work fine for me

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended functionality, there is not away to sync a personal Outlook calendar to a SharePoint calendar for all users to view.